# Grouping and summing time differences from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like in example below:

```
Timestamp           ComponentName Utilization

18.10.2020-19:07.10        A    Available

19.10.2020-21:07.10        A    Available

19.10.2020-19:07.10        A    In use

22.10.2020-19:07.10        A    In use

25.10.2020-19:07.10        A    In use
```

And desired output should be:

```
ComponentName Total_Inuse_time Total_Available_time
    A          6 days     1 day 2 hours
```

Basicly I want to have total inuse time and available time for each component.
I have tried grouping by component names and aggregating with sum on Time differences but could not get the desired result.

Comment: Where do the `1 hours` and `2 hours` come from?

Comment: @user17242583 sorry, 1 line was missing. updated the df now.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But where does the `1 hours` come from for `In use`? The times are all `19:07.10`.

Comment: @user17242583 dont care about that. it s just an example i added it in order to make users understand what i want to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df['Timestamp'] = df.groupby(['ComponentName', 'Utilization'])['Timestamp'].diff().fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))
sums = df.groupby(['ComponentName', 'Utilization'])['Timestamp'].sum()
```

Output:

```py
>>> sums
ComponentName  Utilization
A              Available     1 days 02:00:00
               In use        6 days 00:00:00
Name: Timestamp, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

>>> sums['A']
Utilization
Available   1 days 02:00:00
In use      6 days 00:00:00
Name: Timestamp, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

>>> sums['A']['Available']
Timedelta('1 days 02:00:00')
```